# Enable HTML button from background thread ASP.NET Web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

I'm trying enable a button on the clients side from a background thread once its work is completed. The functionality I'm hoping to achieve is that the user will click the button to run a thread in the background, the button will then disable preventing the user from creating another thread, the thread will complete its work and then enable the button again. Unfortunately `this.button.Enabled=true` doesn't enable when inside the thread block. Note that I'm new to ASP.NET Web Forms and C#.

So far I have:

```cs
protected void BtOnclick(Object sender, EventArgs e){
    
    this.button.Enabled = false;
    Threadstart start = new ThreadStart(this.WorkerThread);
    new Thread(start).Start()
}

protected void WorkerThread(){
    
    /*Here I do some work*/
    this.button.Enabled = true; /* This line is not enabling my button*/
}
```

Comment: If the intent is for the server to signal the client to perform an operation (enable a button, or anything else) then the technology you'd be looking for is called Web Sockets.  Take a look at SignalR for using web sockets in an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as noted, a separate process thread has no http context.
(And, it in general does not have session () either.

I mean, the end user might click on a link to start shopping on amazon, or close the lid on their laptop.

So, given this so-called state-less environment?

Well, what this suggests is you could adopt what is called a web socket from the client side, and then on the server have some code that talks to the client side.

This setup is often used for say a chat page. However, since it can be a boatload of work to setup and write the code to maintain that web socket? Then most suggest to adopt SignalR library.

However, while SignalR can be a great solution (and allows push notifications from the server to client)?

It also quite a bit of moving parts for JUST the simple task you desire.

The simple approach is to have client-side JavaScript code run, say every second. It can make a request to the server to check if the processing is done, and then you can re-enable the button.

However, since a web service call is also state-less? Then that running process will have to update some "value" that not only persists, but belongs to the one user!

That means the only 2 practical places for the "done flag" is session () or some row in a database. However, you have to pass to that separate thread/process the HttpContext.Current for this to work. (And that can cause problems).

So, most easy is to use HttpRuntime.Cache. Keep in mind that this is not per user, but has a context for all users.

So, adding some kind of key, such as userID or some such is required.

So, say this sample markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" 
            Text="Start the process"
            OnClick="cmdStart_Click"
            CssClass="btn" />

        <div id="mywaitdiv" runat="server" style="display:none" clientid="static">
            <h3>Processing - please wait</h3>
            <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" width="48" />
        </div>


        <script>

            function mypoll() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ProcessWait.aspx/CheckDone",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (rstuff) {
                        if (rstuff.d === "done") {
                            $("#cmdStart").prop("disabled", false)
                            $("#mywaitdiv").hide()
                        }
                        else {
                            setTimeout(mypoll, 1000)
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage)
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

So, we click a button, and this code behind runs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void cmdStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdStart.Enabled = false;
        mywaitdiv.Style.Add("Display", "inline");

        HttpRuntime.Cache[logonid + "_MyProcess"] = "running";

        string sJava = "mypoll()";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "startpoll", sJava, true);

        ThreadStart MyProc = new ThreadStart(MyWorker);
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(MyProc);
        MyThread.Start();


    }

    public static void MyWorker()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        HttpRuntime.Cache[logonid + "_MyProcess"] = "done";

    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
    public static string CheckDone()
    {
        return HttpRuntime.Cache[logonid + "_MyProcess"].ToString();
    }
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

I assumed use of jQuery for above JavaScript code.

## Edit: do this with 100% server-side controls

So, a great follow up question in the comments. Can we do this without writing JavaScript and a web method?

The answer is yes, and webforms has this magic trick called an update panel.

So, try these steps.

The update panel will "ajax" this for us, and we don't have to write one line of JavaScript here.

So first, drag in the script manager from the tool box, place it right after your form tag, so we now have this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Ok now for our cool "update" content area and the start button.

Drag in an update panel. So, we have this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then type in "ContentTemplate"

We now have this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>


            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, now we simple place our button and update stuff inside of above (content template area).

And drag in a timer control.

Make sure the timer is set to trigger every 1 second, and make sure "enabled" is false. You can use the property sheet for this control, and that includes the "event" tab area of the property sheet.

So, we now have this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server"
                    Text="Start the process"
                    OnClick="cmdStart_Click"
                    CssClass="btn" />

                <div id="mywaitdiv" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <h3>Processing - please wait</h3>
                    <h4 id="MyStatus" runat="server"></h4>
                    <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" width="48" />
                </div>

                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" 
                    Enabled="False" 
                    Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" >
                </asp:Timer>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now, I also added the "step status" the processing task is working on.

So, our code behind:

```
    protected void cmdStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmdStart.Enabled = false;
        mywaitdiv.Visible = true;

        Session["mystep"] = "Processing Payroll data";
        MyStatus.InnerText = Session["mystep"].ToString();

        ThreadStart MyProc = new ThreadStart(MyWorker);
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(MyProc);
        MyThread.Start();

        Timer1.Enabled = true; // start the timer

    }

    public  void MyWorker()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        // step one done, now work on step 2

        Session["mystep"] = "Sending out emails for payroll";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
        Session["mystep"] = "done";

    }


    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["mystep"].ToString() == "done")
        {
            // we are done, hide the process gif and area, stop the timer
            mywaitdiv.Visible = false;
            Timer1.Enabled = false; // stop timer
            MyStatus.InnerText = "";
            cmdStart.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            MyStatus.InnerText = Session["mystep"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

So, now, the result is this:

[image]

So, note that while we not writing any client-side JavaScript?

Well, we STILL have to adopt a polling approach here.

As noted, if you REALLY want to have push notifications running code server side? Then as suggested, you can adopt SignalR for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance it's much appreciated. I'm curious however how you'd go about this without using AJAX and strictly using ASP.NET?

Comment: See my 2nd post and additional example. I show how to do this 100% with native asp.net controls, and not having to write any JavaScript.